# Magento Backup - required? Little Question

Tags: backup

I´m ready with my first magento shop. I´ve just a little question:
Is it required to backup the system every wekk / months? How strong is magento? Is it possible that the system no longer works at once?

So how do you handle the backup in magento? How often do you backup the system? And what do you backup? database / ftp files / customer export?

Answer (score 2):

You can take **files, Database, media**  backups from `System > tools > backups` as you done with your Magento site, you can take backup now, no need to take any backups until you change something related to files or database, **but before you do any changes** better to take backup of particular files & if you want to do any major database changes, then you need to take DB backup.

Also you can put **Scheduled backup**  in magento by `system > configuration > system > backups` d**aily / week /monthly** once in backend.

These backups will be stored in **`var/backups`** folder, so that you need to copy to your local system.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast answer! What do you think about this extesion: 

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/backup-guard-lite.html 
Can it more than the backup in the magento configuration?

I´ve set up the scheduled backup. Should I save the dadabase and media or system?
Is system the whole shop with the database and the media?

Should I activate the maintenance mode? 

Sorry, it´s my first magento shop...

best regards!

Comment: @Bernd Did you saw the reviews of that extension, some gave bad reviews, as magento only by default providing , for my knowledge no need to install any extension just for backup. try to avoid using extensions as much as possible. & system backup includes all files, db, images.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I, rather than using magento default functionality to take backups, I rely on doing it manually on server level. I have made a sh script (on linux server) which does this periodically for me, get downloaded to a backup server(or my machine) and got deleted when the download is finished. I rely on this because i dont want to make my setup heavy with span of time.

```
cat app/etc/local.xml
```

Get db credentials from here

```
mysqldump -u user_name -ppassword database_name > path_to_document_root/database_name.sql
```

Take database dump and put in document root (or any place you wish)

```
tar -cvf backup.tar site_folder/
```

Compress the site containing files and database from step 2

```
gzip backup.tar
```

This is optional, if you wish to compress it in more smaller size

Download or transfer files using scp or download link. May this help someone looking for an alternative process.